# How to implement a dynamic attribute default in chef LWRP definition

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I would like to be able to define a lightweight resource with let's say 3 parameters, two of them being basic/elementary parameters and the third being a combination of these two. I would also like to provide a possibility of customization of the third parameter. For example:

How to modify following code to achieve above behaviour for the `full_name` attribute:

**resource definition:**

```
actions :install

attribute :name, :kind_of => String, :name_attribute => true
attribute :version, :kind_of => String
attribute :full_name, :kind_of => String
```

**provider definition:**

```
action :install do
    Chef::Log.info "#{new_resource.full_name}"
end
```

I would like to see different outputs for different resource directives, e.g.:

```
resource "abc" do
    version "1.0.1"
end
```

will result in `abc-1.0.1`, but:

```
resource "def" do
    version "0.1.3"
    full_name "completely_irrelevant"
end
```

will result in `completely_irrelevant`.

Is there a possibility to define this behaviour in the resource definition (probably through the `default` parameter) or I am able to do it in provider definition only? If the second is true, then can I store the calculated value in the `new_resource` object's `full_name` attribute (the class seems to miss the `full_name=` method definition) or I have to store it in a local variable?

**Update**

Thanks to Draco's hint, I realized that I can create an accessor method in the resource file and calculate the `full_name` value on the fly when requested. I would prefer a cleaner solution but it's much better than calculating it in action implementation.

**Chef version**
Chef: 10.16.4

Answer (score 3):

Setting @full_name in constructor, similar to providing default action in chef < 0.10.10, as [written in wiki](http://wiki.opscode.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=7274964), does not work, because @version is not set at that point yet.

```
def initialize( name, run_context=nil )
  super
  @full_name ||= "%s-%s" % [name, version]
end
```

So we have to overwrite full_name method in resource by adding

```
def full_name( arg=nil )
  if arg.nil? and @full_name.nil?
    "%s-%s" % [name, version]
  else
    set_or_return( :full_name, arg, :kind_of => String )
  end
end
```

into resource definition. That works. Tested.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that the `version` member variable is `nil` at this point even if it is specified in resource directive. It seems that the attribute value specified in a recipe isn't assigned to the member, yet (when I log its value in the action handler it has a proper value).

Answer (score 1):

```
attribute :full_name, :kind_of => String, default => lazy {|r| "#{r.name}-#{r.version}" }
```

Answer (score 0):

After fighting this for some time, I found this to work cleanly.

`attribute :eman, String, default: lazy {|r| r.name.reverse }`

The part that was missing for me was the `|r|` parameter to the lazy block.

https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#lazy-evaluation